# mysql - Regular Express to find column that starts with letters

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to come up with a regular expression in mysql where it searches a column that starts with a letter. So far I have come up with this which does not work

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE REGEXP '[A-Za-z]%'

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z]'
```

Comment: '^[^A-Za-z]' Negate the character class. EDIT: Wow, you asked to not to start with a letter, dont delete now.

Answer (score 1):

You are close:

```
'^[A-Za-z]'
```

You are dealing with regular expression, so temporary forget about the normal SQL pattern matching syntax.

Check [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) out for more information on regex.

Since REGEXP is not case sensitive unless when used with binary string, you can specify `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]`.

You can use negated character class `[^characters]` if you don't want it to start with some character, but note that everything else not specified will match.

```
'^[^A-Za-z]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE your_column_name REGEXP '^[a-z]'
```

Comment: Correct answer, since the REGEXP is not case sensitive unless the data is binary.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE REGEXP '([A-Z]|[a-z])+%'
```

Comment: This will match anywhere in the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE password REGEXP '^[a-zA-w]'
```

Comment: Why the heck `A-w`? This will cause some non alphabet between `Z` and `a` to match.